# Hide data-binding when loading page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

When reloading a page of my angularJS app, it will show "School:", very ugly. I do not want to show this incomplete information during the page loading.

```
<title>School: {{query}}</title>
```

How to hide it while the page is loading?

Comment: you can use `ng-cloak` directive for this .

Comment: Put 'School: ' within the {{query}} binding.

Comment: @shammelburg it works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using double curlies, a better solution would be to use the `ngBind` or `ngBindTemplate` directives, which are invisible to the user while the page is loading:

```
<title ng-bind-template="School: {{query}}">Querying</title>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you want to achieve this behavior, just add ng-cloak to that html tag. This will prevent the UI from showing the content until the expression is evaluated.

`<title ng-cloak>School: {{query}}</title>`